# How to attach an image to another html element?

Tags: html, css, window, position, element

I have a mat-card in the center of my page. An img is now placed behind the mat-card, in the right top corner.

This is the current html-part:

```
<main class="site-content">

  <img class="Logo" src="assets/YappLogo.png" alt="Logo">
    <mat-card>
      ...
    </mat-card>

</main>
```

This is the current css-part:

```
.site-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: end;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 270px;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The current output is correct, but I want the image to stay in the same position as I change the size of the window. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi @Sarah, can you explain more about what is currently not working and/or how do you define "same position"? Relative to which element?

Comment: Hi, sure, I try. When I minimize the window, the img is wandering and not staying relative to the mat-card element. I want it to stay attached to the mat-card element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the purpose is to have the `.logo` on the right of your `mat-card` where the ordering must be below your `mat-card`, you can make use of creating a wrapper element of size 0px x 0px as an anchor.

After that, making use of the combination of `position: relative` from parent and `position: absolute` from the child, your `.logo` can then "float" besides of your `mat-card` regardless of the size of the window.

The `z-index` also have to be taken care of so that the `logo` is below the `mat-card`.

```css
.site-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
}
mat-card {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Other minor styling not relevant to the question */
.site-content { min-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; } 
body { margin: 0; }
mat-card { display: block; width: 300px; height: 200px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

```html
<main class="site-content">
  <mat-card></mat-card>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="logo" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I put the position on "relative" in the wrapper class, my image is not showing in the browser anymore.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, is there any like special CSS attribute like `overflow: hidden;` on your `.wrapper` selector? Alternatively, maybe you can try using a different name? (Assuming it is caused by clashing with other common class names)